# Issue with custom payment method info not showing in the email on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, payment-methods

I'm stuck on an issue with displaying the payment method details in the email that is sent to client on new orders, this is using a custom payment method that I created. What I have so far is; I have created a module with a block at app/code/local/PayOnDelivery/Block and in it a Info.php file with the following content:

```
class PayOnDelivery_Block_Info extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payondelivery/info.phtml');
    }
}
```

Secondly I have created a info.phtml in app/design/frontend/default/default/template/payondelivery.

I have also created Data.php at app/code/local/PayOnDelivery/Helper, the file is empty with just the class defininition in it (shouldn't need anything else).

```
class PayOnDelivery_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Also I have the necessary PayOnDelivery.php in app/code/local/PayOnDelivery/Model, the file has the necessary functions for the info.phtml to use.

The content of the info.phtml get printed nicely on the page when printing the order confirmation and also on the order page when displaying the order afterwards. For some reason the same content does not get applied to the email that is sent as new order.

I'm using the default order_new.html template for emails but the {{var payment_html}} is ending up empty. Anyone got ideas of the cause? I'm using Magento 1.9...

Comment: anything in var/log?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing :(

Comment: I also got this issue when i created my own custom payment module for CC processing. Everything works fine but the new order email does not have any Payment info. Any advice please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just a guess: your theme is not default? If not try to place the template into base/default.

Comment: Wow this was the correct guess! :) I moved it over, works like a charm now :)

Comment: It did not worked for me. My new order email still does not show any payment information.

Answer (score 0):

its because orderId doesn't set in Params
@ default/template/payment/inf/banktransfer.phtml

after

```
$orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
```

add:

```
if ($orderId==NULL) {
        $shipid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment_id');
        $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipid)->getItemsCollection()->getItems();
    if($shipment!=NULL){
        foreach ($shipment as $value) {
            $dataOrder = $value->getShipment()->getData();
        }

        $orderId = $dataOrder['order_id'];
    }
}
```

its work for me